# Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Mvc' or one of its dependencies. Index not found

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, webgrease

I have created a mvc4 web application. It works on my dev environment but when I deploy it to my production environment (WinHost) it generates following error.

I have already changed copy Local to true

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Mvc' or one of its
>   dependencies. Index not found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131124)
>   Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load
>   file or assembly 'System.Web.Mvc' or one of its dependencies. Index
>   not found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131124)

Source Error:

> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Assembly Load Trace: The following information can be helpful to
>   determine why the assembly 'System.Web.Mvc' could not be loaded.
>
> WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF. To enable assembly bind
>   failure logging, set the registry value
>   [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1. Note: There
>   is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure
>   logging. To turn this feature off, remove the registry value
>   [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].

Stack Trace:

Comment: Did you try redeploying it?  Maybe one of the files didn't get copied correctly.

Comment: Is System.Web.Mvc definitely in the Bin directory? Are you using VS2010 or VS2012?

Comment: System.Web.Mvc exists in Bin Directory and I am using VS2012

Comment: Are both platforms running the same architecture (32bit or 64bit)

Comment: yes both runing 64bits.